# Import iso_date_prefix from django_minio_backend problem

Tags: python, django, minio

I have this exception when running django dev-server:

```
 File "/Users/maxim/PycharmProjects/inventory3/inventory/main/models.py", line 22, in <module>
    **from django_minio_backend import iso_date_prefix**
  File "/Users/maxim/PycharmProjects/inventory3/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_minio_backend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .apps import *
  File "/Users/maxim/PycharmProjects/inventory3/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_minio_backend/apps.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import MinioBackend, MinioBackendStatic
  File "/Users/maxim/PycharmProjects/inventory3/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_minio_backend/models.py", line 30, in <module>
    from django.utils.timezone import utc
**ImportError: cannot import name 'utc' from 'django.utils.timezone'**
```

It started from updating Python's packages to latest versions...